# Service layer pagination, paged results (where to put logic?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, n-tier-architecture

I want to implement paging in my Web API, but from what I saw most paged results contain URLs or links to self, next, previous, last, first.

I'm not sure where to put paging logic, as the service layer can't generate URLs. And I don't want to couple my service layer with ASP NET Core.

How can I accomplish this? I want simple CRUD with paging.

Should controller generate my "Paging" model with URLs etc.? And service would only return `IQueryable`?

Github API, for example, returns pages in "Link" header: https://api.github.com/search/code?q=addClass+user:mozilla&per_page=2

Comment: I suggest the service return only the data, total whereas the controller wraps this result with next and previous page urls.

Comment: @Ramesh any example?

Comment: { data:[], total:0, prev:"", next:"" } where the previous and next are url depending on the pageSize and pageNumber, prev and next will be null if there are no previous or next records.

Comment: @Ramesh I know how to represent this data, but I don't know what should I return from my service to my controller and where to do paging with generated urls

Comment: Your service layer should return the paged data and total (this can be a generic object). Pass this information to the Base Api controller to determine the prev and next url as the API controller will be able to generate those urls based on the current search, pageSize and pageNumber,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The url generation should be included the closer you can to the Mvc/WebApi stuff (inside controllers, filters or whatever mechanism you want), you should not put your url generation inside the service layer unless you have bussiness rules that defined that url generation.

Trying to generate urls from a service layer will force to include HttpContext and Mvc references wich is preferable to elude.

Services should know about business data and not about ui layer components.

Think about it as trying to reuse the same service for a table or a view, then you dont need that url generation stuff. You should return the data, offset,limit, order by and total count (if required) because its needed to query that data, but not the url info.

I usually use something like this with entity framework and crud operations inside services or application layers, it encapsulates pagination simplifying Count and Skip, Take actions

```
/// <summary>
/// Paged queryable
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">T</typeparam>
public sealed class PagedQueryable<T> : IPagedEnumerable<T> ,IEnumerable<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> _source = null;
    int? _totalCount = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Ctor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">source</param>
    /// <param name="offset">start element</param>
    /// <param name="limit">max number of items to retrieve</param>
    public PagedQueryable(IQueryable<T> source, int offset, int? limit)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

        _source = source;
        Limit = limit;
        Offset = Math.Max(offset, 0);
    }

    public int TotalCount
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_totalCount.HasValue && _source != null)
                _totalCount = _source.Count();

            return _totalCount.GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public int? Limit { get; }
    public int Offset { get; }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (_source is IOrderedQueryable<T>)
        {
            var query = _source.Skip(Offset);
            if (Limit.GetValueOrDefault() > 0)
                query = query.Take(Limit.GetValueOrDefault());

            return query.ToList().GetEnumerator();
        }
        else
            return Enumerable.Empty<T>().GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: So I could store my "`Page`" model in my service layer, return that from my services without Urls and then I could create another model in my API layer that wraps this page and adds links?

Comment: I think it is the best aproach, retrieving data with a known interface (as IPagedQueryable for example) and add extensions to generate a IPagedRestful or whatever data structure you need with the urls